Counting the number of ways a four-character PIN can be composed
A PIN is a sequence of four characters which can be composed of English letters and 10 digits. We add additional constraint on a PIN by not allowing repetition of symbols. Moreover, a PIN cannot start with letters A through M and must end only with digits. For example, 1234, ZXY0 are all examples of a PIN.
What's the total number of ways a PIN can be composed?
When I try to solve this problem, I arrive at two different answers.
The first approach I use involves the multiplication rule and reordering:

Choose the right-most symbol;
Choose the left-most symbol;
Choose the second symbol from the left;
Choose the third symbol from the left.

This approach gives 10 * 22 * 34 * 33 = 246840 as an answer.
The second approach is division into cases: there are ((23 * 35 * 34 * 9) + (23 * 35 * 34 * 8) + (23 * 35 * 34 * 7) + (23 * 35 * 34 * 10)) = 930580 ways to compose a PIN since the choice of the last digit depends on how many digits have been chosen on the previous three positions. That is, if only one digit has been chosen on positions one to three, there are 9 available digits for the last position, if two digits have been chosen, there are 8 available digits, and so on.

Your first approach is absolutely correct.
In your second solution the problem is that if you have, for example, only 9 digits available for the last position, that means that at some point a digit was chosen. Then at some position the number of options is not 35 or 34, but 10.

I would greatly appreciate your thoughts on how to compute the answer using division into cases method as all my attempts have miserably failed.

Let c be a character, d a digit. Than you have these options for the first 3 positions: ccc, ccd, cdc, cdd, dcc, dcd, ddc, ddd. Now you can calculate the sum (remember that the number of combinations of, for example, dcd and ddc are the same).

((10 * 26 * 25 * 9) + (13 * 10 * 25 * 9) + (13 * 25 * 10 * 9) + (10 * 9 * 26 * 8) + (13 * 10 * 9 * 8) + (10 * 26 * 9 * 8) + (10 * 9 * 8 * 7) + (13 * 25 * 24 * 10)) is precisely what I was looking for.
